# "cannot create agent , not found - Caused by " creating a JADE container remotely

Tags: java, netbeans-8, agents-jade

I am trying to create a container remotely but the system cannot find the class

this is the setting which is running on netbeans  : 
[image: Arguments]

and this is the error :

```
    Aug 15, 2015 3:53:55 AM jade.core.Runtime beginContainer
INFO: ----------------------------------
    This is JADE 4.3.3 - revision 6726 of 2014/12/09 09:33:02
    downloaded in Open Source, under LGPL restrictions,

----------------------------------------
Aug 15, 2015 3:53:55 AM jade.imtp.leap.LEAPIMTPManager initialize
INFO: Listening for intra-platform commands on address:
- jicp://169.254.222.220:1099

Aug 15, 2015 3:53:55 AM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.management.AgentManagement initialized
Aug 15, 2015 3:53:55 AM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.messaging.Messaging initialized
Aug 15, 2015 3:53:55 AM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.resource.ResourceManagement initialized
Aug 15, 2015 3:53:55 AM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.mobility.AgentMobility initialized
Aug 15, 2015 3:53:55 AM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.event.Notification initialized
Aug 15, 2015 3:53:55 AM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl startBootstrapAgents
SEVERE: Cannot create agent rma: Name-clash Agent rma@169.254.241.140:9000/JADE already present in the platform 
Aug 15, 2015 3:53:55 AM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl startBootstrapAgents

**SEVERE: Cannot create agent BuyerAmjad: Class build.classes.BuyerAgents.BuyerAgent for agent ( agent-identifier :name BuyerAmjad@169.254.241.140:9000/JADE ) not found - Caused by:  build.classes.BuyerAgents.BuyerAgent**


Aug 15, 2015 3:53:55 AM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl joinPlatform
INFO: --------------------------------------
Agent container Container-6@169.254.222.220 is ready.
--------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are starting an RMA agent (with the parameter: -gui) and it seems that there is already one started. You could only have one RMA active.

Another problem could be that the remote system has no access to the original definition of the BuyerAgent you are trying to create. Or at least, you are not stating what MAIN platform the remote one has to join, in order to communicate.

Those would be my first tries to attemp to troubleshoot the system. It's difficult without access to the system.

Hope to have helped.